# Intelligent routing with controller

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, routes, laravel-routing, laravel-5.7

There is a way automatically set routes using my controller's methods?

Example: I have a PagesController with 'home' or 'index', 'about' and 'contact' methods. Can I set routes for every method without explictly typing them?

Something like

```
Route::?('PagesController');
```

or

```
Route::get('/{page}', 'PagesController@{page}');
```

?

*yeah, i'm new in laravel...*

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, it's not possible. Assuming you use standard RESTful methods like index, create, edit, store, update and destroy then yes, you can just write:

```
Route::resource('cars', 'CarController');
```

and you will have created routes for list of cars, route for edit, create and so on

This is explained in [Resource Controller](https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/controllers#resource-controllers) documentation part.

But remember you can always create routes that will "catch" all other urls, for example you could create route like this:

```
Route::get('{page?}', 'PagesController@handle')->where('page', '.+')
```

And this route should be defined as last one from all other routes.

And now you can define handle method in this controller like this:

```
public function handle($page = 'home') 
{
    // here you can put any logic you want, for example:

   if (method_exists($this, $page)) {
       return $this->$page();
   }

   abort(404);
}
```

and now you can define methods that match your urls for example:

```
public function home()
{
   // return some response here
}

public function index()
{
  // return some response here
}
```

This way you should be able to achieve what you want without need of manually defining multiple routes in your routing file.